# Let X is beta distributed, what is the distribution of 1/X?

Tags: probability, distributions, beta-distribution

Let $X \sim Beta(a,b)$. I was wondering what is the distribution of $\frac{1}{X}$?. Here is my derivation by using transformation of random variable.

Let $Y = h (X) = \frac{1}{X}$, which implies $h^{-1} (y) = 1/y$ and $h^{'-1} (y) = -1/y^2$

\begin{align}
f_Y (y) 
&= f_X( h^{-1} (y) ) \left|\frac{d}{dy} h^{-1} (y)\right|\\
&= \frac{1}{B(a,b)} (1/y)^{a-1} (1-1/y)^{b-1} \left|-1/y^2 \right| \\
&= \frac{1}{B(a,b)} (1/y)^{a+2-1} (1-1/y)^{b-1} \\
&= \frac{B(a+2,b)}{B(a,b)} \ \frac{1}{B(a+2,b)}(1/y)^{a+2-1} (1-1/y)^{b-1} \\
&\propto  \frac{1}{B(a+2,b)}(1/y)^{a+2-1} (1-1/y)^{b-1}
\end{align}

Very likely I am wrong on it. But just wondering if I can saying it is still beta distributed? I would appreciate it if someone could pointing out where I am getting wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "But just wondering if I can saying it is still beta distributed?" since beta variates are in $[0,1]$, and things in $[0,1]$ map to $[1,\infty]$ under the mapping $x\to\frac{1}{x}$, we can say without any math that it is not beta distributed.

Comment: When shifted left by $1,$ to make its support the non-negative numbers, this is a Beta Prime distribution.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Related_distributions .  Notice that $1/X-1 = (1-X)/X=Y/(1-Y)$ where $Y=1-X$ has a Beta$(b,a)$ distribution.  This latter transformation, which is the operation performed to convert a probability $Y$ into an odds, is a standard way to go from the Beta to the Beta Prime distribution.

Comment: @JohnMadden thanks a lot. you are correct. I messed up the domain. In the case, the format of the resulted pdf function "looks like" beta density but it is not a beta pdf.

Comment: @whuber thanks, I have been confused by the definition of beta and beta prime for a long time. I think the distribution of 1/X and 1/X-1 are different even the domain is only shifted by 1 in the latter case?

Comment: Of course the distributions differ!  But they differ in the extremely simple way described by subtracting $1.$  Such an inconsequential change never rises to the level of giving the shifted distribution a new name or conducting any special new studies of its properties.

Comment: For some other relations with the beta prime, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/554034/distribution-of-the-exponential-of-an-exponentially-distributed-random-variable/554035#554035